# Programming and drawing to deal with different screen sizes and resolutions

Tags: xna, 2d, monogame

I started making an XNA game years ago and picked it up recently.

I'm looking later to convert it to use Monogame so that it can be deployed on various mobile devices and OS, though I have a sinking feeling that a lot of the sprites and code will be broken by the changing screen sizes when I move outside of the emulator.

The game is currently hard coded to to 800x480 and the level placements and sprite sizes were all done to fit that at the time.

So question:

What do I need to ensure this works and displays properly on a variety of screens and devices?

Comment: There are a great article at Gamasutra.com. Check the page 4:  
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/192209/from_xna_to_monogame.php?page=4

Answer (score 1):

Just scale all of your textures to the ratio of your original 800x480 to the size of their screen.

e.g. if their screen is 1600 x 900

1600 / 800 = 2

900 / 480 = 1.875

scale everything's X by 2 and Y by 1.875, and multiply all positions by the scale.

Comment: Stretching one axis more than another would look...awful and unprofessional.

Comment: Then just scale it by the smaller one and use black bars on the sides.